# calculate the angles for an ellipse to get nearly equal (if not equal) arc lengths based on major and minor axes lengths

Tags: conic-sections

I am trying to get equidistant points on an ellipse. I have the major axis and minor axis. Is there a way to calculate the angles in a loop, where the points are at equal distance on teh ellipse? I know how to calculate points on ellipse based on equal angles, but I would like to get the angle based on equal arc lengths.

Comment: equidistant from where ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I want to get points on the ellipse so that they are equidistant from each other. Or in other words, get the angles such that the arc lengths are the same.

Comment: To find even the case of five equally spaced (in the sense of equal arc-lengths between successive points) has been done, but only by a quite complicated medthod involving elliptic functions. I'd bet googling "five points on ellipse" would get there...